# Get Set Global Variable to use in another function

Tags: laravel

My main idea is passing data with session and get or set with controller to use in model.

This is my **Controller**.

```
$aFilters = $request->all();

if(empty($aFilters)) {

    $aRegions = $this->oChartManager->getRegions();
    $aFilterRegion = [];
    foreach ($aRegions as $aRegion) {
        array_push($aFilterRegion, $aRegion['region']);
    }
    $aFilters['region'] = $aFilterRegion;

}

$request->session()->put('filtered', $aFilters);

$request->session()->put('filtered', $this->oChartManager->addGlobalFilters('region', $aFilters['region']));

$request->session()->put('filtered', $this->oChartManager->getGlobalFilters());
```

This is my **Model**.

```
protected $aGlobalFilters = [];

public function addGlobalFilters($sKey, $mValue) {

    $this->aGlobalFilters[$sKey] = $mValue;
}

public function getGlobalFilters() {

    return $this->aGlobalFilters;
}

public function Info() {

     dd($this->aGlobalFilters ); // This get [] 
}
```

The Problem is i try to get data from controller to use in another function but the data not passing to function Info even i return in `getGlobalFilters()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

Write `$this->x` rather than `$this->$x`

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $x;

    public function index()
    {
        $this->x ='22';
    }

    public function send_message()
    {
        echo $this->x;
    }
}
```